# jQuery ajax success change DOM state?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have the following code for to send ajax to the server. There is an image tag inside "source_html", If the code block inside success() runs, I will see an image not found icon showing up in "target".

However, if the error() runs, I will see an image showing up correctly in "target".

I wonder does jQuery .ajax change some of the DOM states after a successful ajax call?

```
$.ajax({
            url : ajax_url,
            type: "POST",
            data: post_data,
            dataType: "json",
            success:function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
            {
                alert("done");
                var source_html = $(dragged).wrap('<p/>').parent().html();
                $(dragged).unwrap();
                target.find('.image-list').append(source_html);
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
            {
                alert("Oops, something went wrong!");
                var source_html = $(dragged).wrap('<p/>').parent().html();
                $(dragged).unwrap();
                target.find('.image-list').append(source_html);
            }
        });
```

Comment: No. Unrelated, but yick for duplicated code.

Comment: `$(dragged)` <- is this what you mean to target?  That is, does `dragged` hold a valid selector?

Comment: Instead of repeating lines 2-4 in the success and error portions, would be wiser to move them to a 'complete'.

Comment: I have repeated code to demo the actual problem!